# Two excel columns, if duplicates in first column, get data from second column

Tags: excel, count, duplicates, logical-operators

I have two excel columns, where the first column specifies the date a report is published, and the second specifies whether it was on time or late.

In my example, I have 5 dates, where a number of reports were published on each date. The second column specifies whether each report was late or on time.

If there was any report published late on any date, I want to classify that date as late, even though other reports were on time.

So what I have is :

```
Date        On Time or Late?

02/12/2020  On Time

02/12/2020  On Time

04/12/2020  Late

04/12/2020  Late

11/12/2020  On Time

11/12/2020  On Time

11/12/2020  Late

11/12/2020  On Time

18/12/2020  On Time

18/12/2020  On Time

18/12/2020  On Time

18/12/2020  On Time

30/12/2020  On Time
```

And what I want is:

```
Date        On Time or Late?

02/12/2020  On Time

04/12/2020  Late

11/12/2020  Late

18/12/2020  On Time

30/12/2020  On Time
```

Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Thanks

Comment: There are multiple ways to go about this. Which approach would depend on what part of excel you feel most comfortable with, and how often you need to do it. If it's something that need to be done very often, I'd personally make a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following formulas:

to get unique dates if you have O365:

```
=UNIQUE(A2:A14)
```

or in pre O365 use array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$14,MATCH(1,--(COUNTIF($D$1:D1,$A$1:$A$14)=0),0)),"")
```

to get OnTime/Late value use

```
=IFERROR(IF(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$14,D2,$B$2:$B$14,"Late")/D2,"Late","On Time"),"")
```

[image]